# Use common functions and views for web database applications

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, web-applications

I have a design discussion with a collegue.

We are implementing a PHP MySQL database application. In the first instance we have written the Insert Get Update Delete, SelectAll and Search functions for a particular table, writting the table and fieldnames in the code, with several php files, one for the object class, one to draw the HTML table for that table, one for editing a row of that table, one containing the above functions, etc.

The disagreement comes as I have now written generic functions that read/write from the database and draw the HTML taking the table name as a parameter, letting these functions discovers the fieldnames from the database or class. So now that code can be used for any table, with any fields without having to manually go in change each function that needs alteration. I understand there will be cases where more table specific functionality is needed, and this I think that should be done as requirements arise, integrating common parts where possible.

My collegue on the other hand is adamant we should keep a set of files separate for each table, i.e. around 5 php files for each table. The read/write functions written differently in each case, with the need for any changes required for all tables to be affecting 5 x number of tables amount of times.

I can certainly say there will be more than main 15 tables in the database that will at least need basic funcionality.

What approach do you think is most appropriate?

Comment: *Why* is your colleague adamant about keeping a separate set of files for each table?

Comment: He says that data access and visualization will be sufficiently different for each table and use case that passing as paramaters variables such as tablename, classname or fieldsnames, rather than just writing those explicity in the SQL statement, will ulimately require too many if/switch constructs to manage, and that keeping a different set of code for each table, even for such things as "SELECT * FROM Table" and draw an HTML table is a easier to maintain in the long run.

Comment: @alex: Is he right? What does he know that you don't? (My general rule for dealing with adamant designers and programmers is to consider myself ignorant of their understanding until I understand their ignorance.)

Comment: If that were so I can't comprehend why so many "frameworks" have cropped up. I generally thought that was the natural progression. a result I am not intending to build myself a fully fledged framework or phpMyAdmin, but to just implement functionality as necessary step by step, making things work generically where possible and not too complex, instead of copying and pasting the same function with different fieldnames for every new table.

Comment: We decided not to start off using an existing framework first off, although we had a quick look at some, because we haven't done a PHP project in some time and didn't want to have understand the particular architecture and library of a framework before we even had 2 tables to show. We would perhaps move to a one if we get more acquainted with what they do and how.

Comment: He says that from his past experience he just found things easier to maintain with loads of files with manually edited field statements rather trying to pass that information as parameters. All I see is his folder has 40 .php files for what I am doing in 8

Answer (score 2):

One of the important principles in programming is DRY : Don't Repeat Yourself. So, everything common to several usecases should be written once, in a single location.

Now, I've never had to develop an application where each database table had the same, generic, crud pages. If it were the case, it wouldn't be a functional application, but a database management application. Are you sure you aren't redeveloping phpMyAdmin?

Comment: No, i am not deveoloping phpMyAdmin, but as a start the first thing that needed doing was to do the basic display a table and edit each row. I understand anything outside a typical select all will need specific SQL queries, and a view to go with it. But even where possible I believe if such a use case is repeated, then it's code  should be reimplemented to permit it's use in multiple locations.
My collegue says we should have separate select all. get, insert, update, delete functions for each table and in a separate .php file.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the same code to handle several base operations on several tables, I would say you shouldn't write that code more than once : **no need to repeat yourself** :

- it would take more time writing the application
- it would take more time *(and possible cause more bugs)* when maintaining it

A possible solution could be to put as much common code as possible into a single class, common to many tables ; and, then, have a specific class for each table, that would extend that common class.

This way :

- The common code would be written only once
- Each table could have its specific code
- The common code could be overridden for a specific table, if necessary.

About that, see the [**Object Inheritance**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php) section of the manual.

About that common class idea, you could even go farther, and write pretty much no code at all, if your CRUD is generic enough : there are ORM frameworks that might do that for you.

For instance, you might want to take a look at [**Doctrine**](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).

Answer (score 0):

We're on the first stages of development, and we don't have the complete functional specifications for the web application we're developing. Yes, we know, but it's not our fault.

So, we're building some parts keeping them pretty simple and straight-forward so we can build on top of that when we have more details on what to build.

We have a section for clients, for ads, for users, ... and I wanted to keep things separate because we don't know what's coming in the future. Yes, at the moment we have only a few fields and some basic listings and editing pages, but all that will grow.

It's not that I don't want to implement some generic code that we can reuse. It's that we don't know yet what will be the limitations in the near future, and I don't want to write generic code that we'll have to parametrize intensely.

For example, Alex built a generic Update method to which you pass an object and it will create an UPDATE SQL statement and execute it. OK, that's cool, but that doesn't work for the Users section of the web app because we store the password encoded. First, it won't encode the password. Second, if you edit a user and don't enter anything on the password and password-confirmation fields, the old password will remain. So, we have a problem with the generic Update method, and as I see it there are two possible solutions:

a) Parametrize the Update method so if it is modifying a user, keep the password if the password on the object is blank. And encode the password, of course.

b) Override the Update method for the child class.

Alex's implementation didn't use inheritance and he used the generic methods in a static class he'd call this way `DataAccess::Update($object);`. The method takes the table name from the class name as he modified the database to make them match (I prefer "Clients" for the table and "Client" for the class). So, option b is not possible with Alex's implementation.

The way I was trying to build it was keeping separate Update methods for each table. Yes, I was repeating myself but, as I said before, we don't have a full specification, so we don't know how it's going to grow. We have an idea, but we don't have the exact details.

So, the point here is that I don't want to write generic code until we have a much more detailed specification so we can evaluate what can and what cannot be shared between the parts.

Not all sections of the web app work the same and, as JB Nizet said: "If it were the case, it wouldn't be a functional application, but a database management application."

And I can tell you for sure this is not a database management application, even though Alex would say "we're just building a database app." Well, maybe, but a database application is not only showing/modifying the tables. And now, views won't solve all problems.

Again, as JB Nizet said: "If it were the case, it wouldn't be a functional application, but a database management application."

And now I'm repeating myself again, but this time there's no reason for that.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Well, as the debate is now public,,, I will have to say that even though your arguments seem reasonable, the fundamental flaw here is that you assume i meant:

Comment: - for my first effort towards generalization to work perfectly in all unforeseen cases.
- never to expect to have to write special code for special cases.
I have always maintained that special cases will need some effort, however I believe this to be not greater than would be required even if common functionality where kept separate. IMO the gain of keeping the common code in one place far outweighs that concern.